# DKIM - key pair generation recommendations

Tags: openssl, dkim

I wonder if it is okay to generate a key pair (`.key` and `.cert` files) for DKIM like this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -keyout dkim-rsa.key -out dkim-rsa.cert
```

By reading [RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.3) I can see that standards only demand RSA algorythm `sha256` and maximum length of `2048`. Are there any other recommenrdations that you would have for me before I create the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With DKIM you don't create an X.509 certificate, but just private and public keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

As the public key is not given in the message but fetched from the DNS it doesn't require the additional features of an X.509 certificate.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this sentance: "As the public key is not given in the message but fetched from the DNS it doesn't require the additional features of an X.509 certificate."

Comment: It doesn't require to be signed by a PKI like e.g. TLS certificates, as the DNS is it's PKI. If you need a stronger PKI for your DKIM, you could protect your DNS zone with DNSSEC.

Comment: Ah! So I can treat DNS as a CA (not trusted), but if I use DNSSEC DNS is like a trusted CA?

Comment: It's similar PKI, but unlike with TLS it's not based on multiple independent root CAs that all can issue certificates for any hostname.